# How to display the contents of a document set on a page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-set

I want to display the contents of a document set (that contains both folders and files) on a page (with the same structure as they are in the document set like folders and files).  How to achieve this?

I tried content search webpart but it is of no use as it displays the flat list instead I need folders and files as they are present in the document set

I tried document set contents webpart but as it doesn't accept any connection, it is not of much use.

I will be glad if you have any pointers for me in this regard.

Regards